# Painless script creates duplicate for keyword property type

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

Currently right now I have a document mapping which looks like as below . When I try to partial update via painless script I always end up inserting duplicate value in **_someproperties** attribute. Also could someone point where is the issue that leads to this failure

```
{
  "companies_nested2" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "dynamic" : "strict",
      "properties" : {
         "_someproperties" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
        }
}
}
}
}
```

```
POST someindex/_update/some_id
{
  "script": {
    "source": "if(params.property_one) { for (long id: params.addIds){if (!ctx._source._someproperties.contains(id)) { ctx._source._someproperties.add(id)} }}",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "property_one": true,
      "addIds": [4919]
    }
  }
}
```

As mentioned this is what I tried if I ran the script multiple times it leads to duplicate,

```
POST someindex/_update/some_id
{
  "script": {
    "source": "if(params.property_one) { for (long id: params.addIds){if (!ctx._source._someproperties.contains(id)) { ctx._source._someproperties.add(id)} }}",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "property_one": true,
      "addIds": [4919]
    }
  }
}
```

but it results in duplicate

```
"_source" : {
          "id" : some_id,
          "_someproperties" : [4919, 4919]
}
```

Comment: What's the field type of _someproperties ? When I try you script ,error occrus : "cannot convert MethodHandle(String,CharSequence)boolean to (Object,long)boolean"

Comment: The field type is keyword and what I want to save is a list of long